# Mule flow calling a secure REST endpoint

Tags: rest, authentication, mule, cloud-foundry

I have a Mule flow running in Cloud foundry. The flow listens to MQ and on receiving a message will call a REST endpoint that resides in a separate web application hosted outside of cloud foundry.

I want to secure the REST endpoint so that it can only be called by the mule flow. Can anyone advise a straightforward way of achieving this? (most articles i've seen seem to be around securing an API within Mule, whereas as this is Mule calling out to a secure REST api.

Any pointers or reference articles would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to enable 2 way authentication. If you provide the Mule client with a certificate and make your REST endpoint only trust that one you are all set.

Comment: Hi afelisatti, would you have any links to resources to help me set this up?

Comment: You can read about TLS in Mule here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/tls-configuration. You basically need to 1) use HTTPS 2) set up a key store in the Mule client 3) set up a trust store on your REST endpoint that only contains an entry for the Mule client